# MissingMethodException even when CF v3.5 is installed?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am trying build & run some proprietary libraries to work on a new WinCE 5.0 device.  I have used the same code on a different (6.0) device with no problems.   They are already working in production around the world, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.  :-)

When I write the simplest bit of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Contains
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String target = "one";
            String expose = "let me be the one";

            Console.WriteLine(expose.Contains(target));
        }
    }
}
```

...at runtime, I get a MissingMethodException for System.String.Contains.

I'm surprised by this, because msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.80).aspx) says that the method has been included since .NET 2.0.  I get the same runtime exception reported whether the above code is with a Framework Version of 2.0 or 3.5.

FWIW, this is not the only method that seems to be missing, Environment.NewLine, StringBuilder.AppendFormat also throw the same runtime exception.

cgautil reports [3.5.7283.0 and 2.0.7045.0] versions of the Compact Framework on the device.

Comment: Is there a reason both frameworks are installed?  If possible remove one of them (2.0).  It's very likely that you're seeing an artifact of a mixed assembly load process.

Comment: Good suggestion.  2.0 is on the ROM, so it can't be uninstalled.  When I uninstall 3.5, and build with target framework = 2.0, I still get the same error that String.Contains() is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me if you have added namespace system on top of your code file. as I can not see any other reason for this. you only have to use.

using System;

on top of the code file and you can use it. it doesn't matter if you have 3.5 or both.

use this:

```
using System;


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string target = "one";
    string expose = "let me be the one";

    Console.WriteLine(expose.Contains(target));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought the namespace, using, and class declaration were implicit.  I edited the post to reflect your question.
Yes, I agree, it shouldn't matter if I have 2.0 or 3.5.  That's the question.

Comment: If it were missing, this wouldn't affect runtime, only compile time.

Comment: use string instead of String as described in my answere